# Installation of Just man Pages and Documentation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clang, manpage

How do I install just the documentation and man pages of Clang and LLVM? I compiled the current version from source, based on the source from the LLVM website and it works fine but since it is a local self-contained repository (it can run from your home directory assuming you have it's bin subdirectory in your path) it does not install the man pages or documentation. I uninstalled the Debian/Ubuntu (I am running both) package of Clang/LLVM to avoid any possible conflicts but this also removed the Clang man pages. How do I install just the man pages and documentation. I am OK if the man pages are technically from a couple of versions back compared to the installed compiler if necessary.

Comment: The source package should certainly be able to install the documentation, too. Examine the Makefile to find the target to install the documentation (something like `/usr/local/share/man` ought to be the default) or tweak your `MANPATH` to point to the source build directory and/or documentation directory.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed your locally compiled clang correctly, and in full, you probably also 'installed' the `man` pages in a sub-directory of `$HOME`, along with the binaries which, as you say, went into `$HOME/bin` (or wherever). The `man` program looks for manual pages in some pre-configured directories, plus those mentioned in the environment variable `MANPATH` (much like `PATH`). You probably need to add the directory where your man pages got installed to your `$MANPATH`, and export it.

The manual for `man` talks about `MANPATH`: http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/man.1.php